# Visual Studio stopped recognizing any include files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

So, I was randomly working on my project and visual studio 2017 was recognizing all my OpenCV stuff just fine, but randomly all of a sudden, it stopped recognizing it right while I was in the middle of coding it, there's errors all over the place saying that functions from OpenCV are undefined and that the source files cannot be opened, this literally makes no sense as it was just working and I had gotten stuff to compile and then all of a sudden in the middle of coding, it just will refuse to recognize anything, I'm really confused and I checked the include and library files and everything was just the same as it was when I had started out, I think something might be wrong with Visual Studio, but I have no idea what to do. I even tried restarting my computer to see if that fixed it, but I'm still stuck in the same boat :/

Edit: Interesting note, when I go to access the project properties, it no longer says  properties, it just says properties, could it be a corrupt project?

Comment: could be some corrupted project or corrupted cache

Comment: reboot, run a manual `chkdsk /f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so Richard Critten's suggestion of doing a chkdsk /f worked, I rebooted to have it check my main disk and now it oddly requires me to specify a folder in the include directory which I didn't have to do before which is odd, but now it's finally working and recognizing everything as it should. Thanks for the help, I just had never seen it before do that while in the middle of a project randomly which severely confused me.